# Is it possible to return html from an Angular service?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Right now I have a service that returns a long string. That string is then being rendered in a markdown directive (wiz-markdown) in one of the templates.

Is there anyway for me to include styling/markup in the string that is returned from the service?

```
`return ("Hey "+name+"!  \r\n\n" +
"Words words Words words Words words Words words Words words  "+
"Words words Words words Words words Words words Words words "+
"Words words Words words Words words Words words , "+
"Words words Words words Words words Words words  "+ 
"Words words Words words .\r\n\n")`
```

Comment: yes, it's possible.

Comment: you can return a string from a service that contains HTML markup.
if you want to use it within angular you can use ng-bind-html to render it to the DOM

Comment: @Tik because a service is a .js file, how would you add markup to the string?

Comment: Couldn't you use ES6 templates? You know, the back-tick-instead-of-quotes thing. However...note that I would probably not return the HTML from the service. I would probably return the data, and either build the HTML in the component you injected the service into (makes more sense if you think about it since the component's template is concerned with the html, not the service, which is only concerned with the data), or from some other utility that does nothing take data objs and returns the html strings (in case you needed that same builder logic for more than one component).

Comment: BTW if that doesn't work (and for some reason I think ES6 templates can be problematic for this sometimes), theres always the option to use the codes for the symbols, e.g "&lt;html&gt;", which would be interpreted as the brackets you'd expect. You also use single quotes to wrap the string and double quotes within it, etc. I think I had to do this somewhere recently for some reason. Lastly, have you tried just coding the markup as usual? I think "it just works". Now that I think about it, that's how I usually go about it.

Comment: you can just add it in 
return `<p> foo <b> bar</b></p> of course you may need to find a way to programatically build the markup into the string